# jquery ajax PUT adding local url to passed url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a file to s3 through ajax.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: url,
      contentType: application/octet-stream,
      processData: false,
      crossDomain: true,
      data: file,
    })
    .success(function() {
      alert('File uploaded');
    })
    .error(function() {
      alert('File NOT uploaded');
      console.log( arguments);
    });
```

It is not working as it is adding `http://localhost:1337/api/v1` in front of the actual url so it fails and gives me `404: Not found error`

[image: Error screenshot]

Same thing works If I use this:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('PUT', url);
  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if(xhr.readyState === 4){
      if(xhr.status === 200){
        console.log('200 status')
      }
      else{
        alert('Could not upload file.');
      }
    }
  };
  xhr.send(file);
```

Comment: i believe you need to use POST instead of PUT

Comment: @Se0ng11 I did and got the same error

Comment: have u debug ur server side whether it did fire the file to your server? you should also found some info in ur browser console

Comment: @Se0ng11 It is not reaching server side as the url is wrong because it is appending the local url in front of the main url (which I am passing).

Comment: Do a `console.log()` of your `url` variable and make sure it's not malformed

Comment: yes, what is your `url`? where did it assign for? it is custom create url?

Comment: @Se0ng11  After `http://localhost:1337/api/v1` is the actual url that I am passing. Don't know why `http://localhost:1337/api/v1` is getting appended

Comment: @MikaelLennholm Yes I checked and the url I am passing is correct

Comment: What are the first **two** characters of `url`, as printed by `console.log()`?

Comment: what about remove the `contentType`? have u try b4?

Comment: @MikaelLennholm `https:` this if you asking about the main url that I am passing

Comment: @Se0ng11 yeah. Didn't work

Comment: if the `url` is correct, thats weird why it append at the front, are there any route being configure somewhere that change how the url being sent? i

Comment: @Se0ng11 Yeah even I am looking for that. But nothing yet

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this..

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: url,
  contentType: application/octet-stream,
  processData: false,
  crossDomain: true,
  data: file,
  success: function(data) {
  alert('File uploaded');
  }
  error: function(data) {
  alert('File NOT uploaded');
  console.log( arguments);
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes. Gives me same error. Still appends the local url in front

Answer (score 0):

You have to urlEncode your url parameter that is a 'url'.
use encodeURI() or encodeURIComponent(),
your example should be:

var url = "http://localhost:1337/api/v1?myurl="+encodeURIComponent("https//ntnx.portal......");

after your server side script get the post, get your url by parameter 'myurl'

Comment: all value you want to pass must in url parameter, like ?abc=xxx&cde=yyy, value(like xxx,yyy) must be url encoded. and don't forget parameter must be start with '?' and by the way, url parameter have limitation in size, better use post.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but in case anyone else finds it, here's the issue I found: I initially typed the url like this:

```
url: "http:/{insert_url}"
```

just adding another forward slash, like this, fixed the problem entirely for me.

```
url: "http://{insert_url}"
```